# fwrite fopen blocking threads

Tags: linux, pthreads

I have a multithreaded linux app written in c running on a i.mx6 arm.  I have a 25lc256 spi eeprom mapped to the file system.  Writes are relatively slow at the driver level, not much can be done there.  The problem is that file functions are blocking other threads for too long.  usleep additions don't seem to help, it appears I'll have to do something different, but its not clear to me what to change.

The output on this calling this function from one thread is

> EEprom write
>  EEprom saved in 522.000000  703.000000  705.000000 
>   723.000000  662596.000000  1328858.000000
>  Capture -EPIPE snd_pcm_prepare

With Capture -EPIPE snd_pcm_prepare coming from the thread where the audio buffer underran because of the blocked thread, I suppose.

```
int SaveCurrentConfig(void) {//EEPROM
    int r = 1;
    struct timeval tvs, tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6;
    gettimeofday(&tvs, NULL);
    printf("EEprom write\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&eepromconfigmutex);
    {
        char * ConfigXml = BuildXmlConfig();
        FILE * WriteConfig = fopen(ConfigPath, "w");
        if (WriteConfig == NULL) {
            MyLog("Unable to open eeprom %s\n", strerror(errno));
            r = 0;
            goto badfinish;
        }
        gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
        size_t len = strlen(ConfigXml);
        unsigned short CRC = ComputeChecksum(ConfigXml, len);
        fwrite((char*) &len, 1, sizeof (size_t), WriteConfig);
        gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
        fwrite((char*) &CRC, 1, 2, WriteConfig);
        gettimeofday(&tv3, NULL);
        fwrite(ConfigXml, 1, strlen(ConfigXml), WriteConfig);
        gettimeofday(&tv4, NULL);
        fseek(WriteConfig, ConfigOffset2, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite((char*) &len, 1, sizeof (size_t), WriteConfig);
        fwrite((char*) &CRC, 1, 2, WriteConfig);
        fwrite(ConfigXml, 1, strlen(ConfigXml), WriteConfig);
        gettimeofday(&tv5, NULL);
        fclose(WriteConfig);
badfinish:
        free(ConfigXml);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&eepromconfigmutex);
    gettimeofday(&tv6, NULL);
    double diff1 = time_diff(tvs, tv1);
    double diff2 = time_diff(tvs, tv2);
    double diff3 = time_diff(tvs, tv3);
    double diff4 = time_diff(tvs, tv4);
    double diff5 = time_diff(tvs, tv5);
    double diff6 = time_diff(tvs, tv6);

    printf("EEprom saved in %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f\n", diff1, diff2, diff3, diff4, diff5, diff6);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that thread calling `fclose()` is blocking other threads from running for long periods, then the problem is likely that it is spending a lot of time in kernel mode inside the eeprom driver code, flushing out the pending writes.

There's a few things you could try:

- Ensure you're running a kernel with the `PREEMPT` configuration option selected.  This will allow the thread to be preempted while it's running the eeprom driver code.
- In conjunction with the first suggestion, set a higher scheduling priority for the sound thread (and/or a lower scheduling priority for the eeprom writing thread).
- Change your code to flush the writes out to the eeprom more frequently by calling `fflush()` after writing a smaller block of data (you may need to also call `fsync()` on the underlying file descriptor).

Comment: I think this best explains what is happening here.  I think the best option is to raw spi in userspace rather than mess with thread priorities.

Comment: Userspace driver does this write in about 1/3 the time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in `fclose()`. `fclose()`, but default, will not return until the contents of the file have been written to disk. I believe you can force it to return early with `O_NONBLOCK`, from `man 2 open`:

> O_NONBLOCK or O_NDELAY
>
> ```
>    When possible, the file is opened in  nonblocking  mode.   Neither
>    the  open()  nor  any subsequent operations on the file descriptor
>    which is returned will cause the calling process to wait.  For the
>    handling  of FIFOs (named pipes), see also fifo(7).  For a discus‐
>    sion of the effect of O_NONBLOCK  in  conjunction  with  mandatory
>    file locks and with file leases, see fcntl(2).
> ```

You can try this out with:

```
int fd = open(ConfigPath, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
FILE * WriteConfig = fdopen(fd, "w");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try an

```
fflush( WriteConfig );
```

just before your

```
fclose(WriteConfig);
```